# Safari on iOS Loading Incorrect Images

Tags: ios, safari

On iOS Safari, PNGs are being loaded in the wrong place. For example, I have some PNG icons, but Safari is not using the correct images that I defined the path to. It is picking random images from the DOM and swapping them with other image locations. I noticed it does not do this as frequently on WiFi as it does on Mobile Wireless.

You may or may not be able to replicate the issue on iOS/Safari by going to this site and scrolling down to the number ticker. The icons here may appear swapped with other images on the page. If you cant replicate it, but have seen this issue in the past and know of a resolution to try, please feel free to offer suggestions.

http://www.easycleanenergy.com/

I found an old post on Apples support forum, but it is 2 years old and I was hoping someone figured out the issue and the fix by now:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6574663?tstart=0
They recommend clearing the browser cache, which works - but the images get swapped again the next time I visit the site. Hopefully you folks have a better solution.

I have not provided code as I don't think it is the current code that is causing it and I honestly would not know what code to post even if it was a code issue - seems to be browser specific to iOS Safari. However, please feel free to view source on the page I linked if you suspect the markup to be the issue and have a suggestion.

Wish I could provide more details - but this information is all I have to work with in debugging this issue. Thanks folks!

Answer (score 2):

I've seen the same issue on a site that I am responsible for.  We had a page for our organization with photos of our leadership team next to their name and biographical information.  On iOS we were seeing images loading next to the incorrect name and bio.  We determined that this issue happens only on iOS (we tested with version 9.3.2) and that it only happens for us when we use IMG tags.  We remediated the issue for this particular page by showing images as background-images of DIV elements and that seemed to resolve the issue.  Hopefully Apple will fix the problem on their end soon!

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was just me and I would never find an answer. I will give this a shot and see how it goes. Thank you again.